# Detect if object is either an Array or typed array

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

I need to determine whether a given object is either an `Array`, or typed array such as `Float32Array`.

Currently I'm checking whether the `.length` property is defined, but this isn't always indicative of an array. Similar issues arise with existence checking of `.forEach()` or other methods.

Several `instanceof` checks would suffice, as done [here](https://github.com/hughsk/is-typedarray/blob/master/index.js) - but I'm wondering if there is a simple built-in feature, e.g., a generic `Array.isArray()` function that does what I need.

Answer (score 7):

```js
function isArrayOrTypedArray(x) {
    return Boolean(x && (typeof x === 'object') && (Array.isArray(x) || (ArrayBuffer.isView(x) && !(x instanceof DataView)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is.

You can do the `instanceof` checks you mentioned, or you could check the result of `Object.prototype.toString.call(variable)` to see if it's one of the predefind strings (`"[object Array]"`, `"[object Uint8Array]"`, etc.). *(Edit: Ah, I see by following the link in your question that that's also demonstrated by that code.)*

Answer (score 0):

While I think, as T.J. Crowder already said, there's no *built-in* function, you should be able to combine [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) and [`ArrayBuffer.isView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/isView) to get the functionality you want:

```
function isArrayOrTypedArray(x) {
  return Array.isArray(x) || (ArrayBuffer.isView(x) &&
      Object.prototype.toString.call(x) !== "[object DataView]");
}
```

`Array.isArray(x)` returns true if `x` is an array. `ArrayBuffer.isView(x)`returns true if `x` is a typed array or DataView, so we just need to ignore the case where `x` is a DataView to get the function we want.

**Demonstration:**

```js
function isArrayOrTypedArray(x) {
  return Array.isArray(x) || (ArrayBuffer.isView(x) && Object.prototype.toString.call(x) !== "[object DataView]");
}

console.log(isArrayOrTypedArray());                    // false              
console.log(isArrayOrTypedArray({}));                  // false
console.log(isArrayOrTypedArray(null));                // false
console.log(isArrayOrTypedArray(undefined));           // false
console.log(isArrayOrTypedArray(new ArrayBuffer(10))); // false

console.log(isArrayOrTypedArray([]));                  // true
console.log(isArrayOrTypedArray([1,2,3,4,5]));         // true
console.log(isArrayOrTypedArray(new Uint8Array()));    // true
console.log(isArrayOrTypedArray(new Float32Array()));  // true
console.log(isArrayOrTypedArray(new Int8Array(10).subarray(0, 3))); // true

var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(2);
var dv = new DataView(buffer);
console.log(isArrayOrTypedArray(dv)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function isArray(array) {
    if((array.length || array.length === 0) && (array.constructor !== String)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Note that a `String` also has a length property and we need to exclude that, hence the `constructor` check.

Comment: Any custom class that has a `length` property will be a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if `x` is an ArrayBuffer,
You can take advantage of the fact that `new DataView(x)` throws "TypeError: First argument to DataView constructor must be an ArrayBuffer" if `x` isn't an ArrayBuffer.

In other words, simply do:

```
function isArrayBuffer(x) {
    try {
        new DataView(x);
        return true;
    }
    catch (TypeError) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And to test if a thing is a TypedArray,
I believe `ArrayBuffer.isView` does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `obj.constructor.name` as a way of getting the object's name rather than an `instanceof` matching ladder.
What all these arrays have in common is they have `Array` in their classname and a `array.length` property which is a number.

```
function isArray(x) {
  if (typeof x.length === 'number' 
    && x.constructor.name.includes('Array')) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This works in later versions of Javascript/Node anyway.
You could use `name.includes` if your JS version supports it.

`Array.constructor.name` is `Array` for `[]` and others like `Uint8Array` for typed arrays.

In other versions of JavaScript you may need `obj.prototype.constructor.name`.